# How to silent logon SAP with SAPRouter in VBA?

Tags: excel, sap-gui, silent

SAP GUI Version:740;
EXCEL:2016 (64X)

I can connect via VBA to SAP with the following code (example parameters):

```vb
Dim sapLogon As SAPLogonCtrl.SAPLogonControl
Dim sapConn As SAPLogonCtrl.Connection

Public Sub Logon()
    Set sapLogon = New SAPLogonControl
    Set sapConn = sapLogon.NewConnection

       With sapConn
        .System = "PRP"                    
        .ApplicationServer = "123.456.789.12"     
        '.SAPRouter = "/H/123.456.789.24/S/3299/H/" 'comment this line
        .SystemNumber = "00"             '
        .Client = "100"
        .User = "user"
        .Password = "mypassword"
        .Language = "EN"
    End With

    Call sapConn.Logon(0, True) 

     If sapConn.IsConnected <> tloRfcConnected Then
       MsgBox "connectiong failed." & sapConn.IsConnected

       Exit Sub
     Else

     MsgBox "connecting successful"
    End If
End Sub
```

I want connect another SAP system `SID:"P95"`  which is not in the same `domain.so`, i use `SAPRouter` parameter ,remove the comment line

```vb
 .SAPRouter = "/H/123.456.789.24/S/3299/H/" 'the value is copy form SAP GUI with 'P95'
```

it can not connect 'P95', the result is

> connectiong failed. 8

I guess the reason is security policy in 'P95'

but it  is strange that if I change the code:

```vb
Call sapConn.Logon(0,True)
```

to

```vb
Call sapConn.Logon(0,False)
```

and also comment the line

```
.SAPRouter = "/H/123.456.789.24/S/3299/H/"
```

then select SAP system : 'P95' in dialog 'SAP logon' and input my password,

It can logon 'P95'

I also find the TAB 'Server' has fill values with the first SAP SID configs( MY SAP GUI has many SAP SID)

SO, how to solve this problem or we can not connect SAP via this way.

Thanks.

Comment: I can logon all the SAP systems in SAP GUI.